# How do I add highlight to an SVG element?

Tags: svg, filter

Assume a have a rect in an SVG element. A red one. I can add another rect positioned on top of it with the colour rgba(255,255,255,0.7) to highlight it.

Is it possible to highlight the rect without adding a second SVG rect element? Perhaps with a CSS filter: ?

Comment: you could just recolour the rect you already have.

Comment: I want the highlight to be the same colour - just lighter. So if the colour is red - how do you lighten it, keeping in mind that the colour could be anything - not just red? Covering it as I have been doing with a semi opaque white rect does this - but is it possible to do it without adding a new rect to the scene?

Comment: opacity perhaps. Or apply a filter perhaps.

Answer (score 0):

CSS filters don't reliably affect child elements of the SVG parent. You'll have to dynamically add an SVG filter using JavaScript. Here is a brightness filter.

```
<filter id="brighter">
  <feColorMatrix type="matrix" values="1.2 0 0 0 0 
                                       0 1.2 0 0 0
                                       0 0 1.2 0 0 
                                       0 0 0 1 0"/>
</filter>
```

Comment: I have this:     <svg width="300" height="300" style="border: 1px solid gray">
        <defs>
            <filter id="brighter">
                <feColorMatrix type="matrix" values="1.2 0 0 0 0 
                                                     0 1.2 0 0 0
                                                     0 0 1.2 0 0 
                                                     0 0 0 1 0"/>
            </filter>
        </defs>
        <rect x="10" y="10" width="100" height="100" fill="red" filter="url(#brighter)"></rect>
    </svg> but no worky. Is there a typo?

Comment: Ah. The brightness filter works in the RGB color space - so if you have a pure red, that's as bright as it goes :) But you can kind of hack a luminance increase with: values="1.2 0.2 0.2 0 0  0.2 1.2 0.2 0 0  0.2 0.2 1.2 0 0 0 0 0 1 0"